# eclipse  crashes while trying to build

Tags: eclipse, build, crash-reports

I was wondering if someone could explain why my eclipse is crashing. Eclipse says its trying to build and then there is a message not responding and I receive this message as eclipse close in figure 1

[image]

figure 1

Comment: Needs substantially more detail. What version of Eclipse?  What OS?  Crash on other people's machines or just yours?  Do other projects build OK?  Does a trivial project build OK?

Comment: I am sorry I will be more descriptive. No projects build ineclipse just crashes . The version I am using is indego

Answer (score 0):

The startup jvm memory allocated to eclipse seems to be low, in the screenshot provided:
-Xms40m -Xmx512m

Increasing these values might provide eclipse more memory to build project.
(Try closing all unused projects in the eclipse workspace)

Assuming your machine has RAM > 2-3 GB,
Modify the file eclipse.ini (in your case at C:\eclipse\eclipse.ini)

Update values of '-Xms' and '-Xmx' to following

```
....
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Memory dedicated to eclipse .

this is the way my problem solved

fist :~>locate eclipse.ini

/home/ your - user /eclipse/eclipse.ini

Second

vi /home/ your - user /eclipse/eclipse.ini

> -startup
>   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar

--launcher.library

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316

-product

org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

-showsplash

org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m

Then change This lines 
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m  // mine was 256
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m   // mine was 512
-Xms512m   // mine was 40
-Xmx2048m // mine was 512

Done :)